# Can see the terminal output but cannot save it to file using shell redirector

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew, stdout, child-process

[The content is on stdout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ydM0.png)

I'm trying to get the result of this package using Nodejs. I have been trying to use spawn, exec and log the child_process object to debug it but cannot see the value on stdout, even though the stderr data is ok.

when I direct terminal output, I'm able to log the stderr, but stdout is just empty if I log it to file, but it does show up in the terminal.

Then I tried using just the tool to check result then thought it's the tool problem, not the Nodejs code.

EDIT: Adding terminal content in text

```
Macbooks-MacBook-Pro:query macos$ lola --formula="EF DEADLOCK" input.lola --quiet --json
{"analysis": {"formula": {"parsed": "EF (DEADLOCK)", "parsed_size": 13, "type": "deadlock"}, "result": true, "stats": {"edges": 3, "states": 4}}, "call": {"architecture": 64, "assertions": false, "build_system": "x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0", "error": null, "hostname": "Macbooks-MacBook-Pro.local", "optimizations": true, "package_version": "2.0", "parameters": ["--formula=EF DEADLOCK", "input.lola", "--quiet", "--json"], "signal": null, "svn_version": "Unversioned directory"}, "files": {"net": {"filename": "input.lola"}}, "limits": {"markings": null, "time": null}, "net": {"conflict_sets": 6, "filename": "input.lola", "places": 8, "places_significant": 6, "transitions": 7}, "store": {"bucketing": 16, "encoder": "bit-perfect", "threads": 1, "type": "prefix"}}
Macbooks-MacBook-Pro:query macos$ lola --formula="EF DEADLOCK" input.lola --quiet --json 2> aaa.txt
{"analysis": {"formula": {"parsed": "EF (DEADLOCK)", "parsed_size": 13, "type": "deadlock"}, "result": true, "stats": {"edges": 3, "states": 4}}, "call": {"architecture": 64, "assertions": false, "build_system": "x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0", "error": null, "hostname": "Macbooks-MacBook-Pro.local", "optimizations": true, "package_version": "2.0", "parameters": ["--formula=EF DEADLOCK", "input.lola", "--quiet", "--json"], "signal": null, "svn_version": "Unversioned directory"}, "files": {"net": {"filename": "input.lola"}}, "limits": {"markings": null, "time": null}, "net": {"conflict_sets": 6, "filename": "input.lola", "places": 8, "places_significant": 6, "transitions": 7}, "store": {"bucketing": 16, "encoder": "bit-perfect", "threads": 1, "type": "prefix"}}
Macbooks-MacBook-Pro:query macos$
```

Comment: Hi. Please put textual information (such as Terminal window content) in your question **as text**, not an image. For example, we can't copy and paste your commands, either as part of an answer or to test and try to reproduce your issue. That said, the last command shown in your image seems reasonable. There's no output to the terminal, as I would expect because you redirected it. Are you saying that your aaa.txt file is empty after that command?

Comment: Thanks for quick support! The file is empty after I log to it using ">", when I tried to log using "2>", the json is still on terminal, this means it is stdout. That is what I'm trying to say with the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like the issue isn't really nodejs related. I did some quick googling on this Lola tool, and it looks like it might have some custom stdout/stderr, so it is possible for it to behave differently when used regularly from the terminal than when you specify redirects for the stdout and stderr.

One possible fix for you would be to use the `--json` option and specify a temporary filename, then have your nodejs code read the result from the temporary file created. (If you can't figure out the stdout/stderr issue.)

Comment: Thank you for your dedicative support! 
I know that workaround, but down the road, the number of queries might be quite explosive because of the state space on petrinet, so writing/reading through file might defect the performance badly.
So I'm trying to get another workaround without doing too much I/O on the server.

Comment: @DangDuyNam OK.  I would try explicitly asking it to write JSON to stdout using `--json=-` (specifying a single dash for the output file should instruct it to write to stdout).  For example, `lola --json=- >stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt` - and see what (if anything) is written to the two files.

Comment: Thank you, I tried what you suggest. The stderr.txt contains the part of output (without json), the stdout.txt is still empty, the json just doesn't write to any one of those.

Here is the command I tried: lola --formula="EF DEADLOCK" input.lola --json=-  >stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt